# Hardness of Short Interger Solution in Lattices

Tags: lattice-crypto, sis

Short Integer Solution ($SIS_{n,m,q,\beta}$) is defined as:

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Z}_{q}^{n \times m}$, find a non-zero vector $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{m}$ such that $A \cdot x = 0\mod q$ and $||x|| \le \beta $.

In the paper [*Trapdoors for hard lattices and new Cryptographic Constructions*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/432.pdf), SIS is proved to be hard by reducing standard worst-case lattice problem approx. SIVP to SIS i.e., if we solve a random instance of SIS, then any instance of approx. SIVP is solved.

In the paper [*On the complexity of computing short Linearly Independent Vectors and Short Bases in a lattice*](http://cs.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/informatik/fg/cuk/Forschung/Publikationen/short.pdf), approx. SIVP is proved to be NP-COMPLETE.

By this, can we say Short Integer Solution (SIS) problem in lattices is NP-Complete?

Comment: Is SIVP reduced to SIS or is it approximate SIVP?

Answer (score 8):

No, we cannot say that Short Integer Solution ($SIS$) problem is NP-Complete.

The results from those two papers are not directly related like that, because on the first one, the reduction is from $SIVP_\sqrt{n}$ to $SIS$ while in the second paper, $SIVP_c$ is proven to be NP-Hard for any *constant* $c$.

Until now, there is no proof that $SIVP_\sqrt{n}$ is NP-Hard and, since [it has been proven to be in the intersection of NP and coNP](https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/crp.pdf#page=17), researchers believe that it is not NP-Hard.